# Python call a function inside another function

Tags: python

How to call a function inside another function in python (not to write a function within another function).

```
class OrderDetails(Document):
  def validate(self):

    # Remove duplicates
    found={}
    #global nfound
    i=-1
    #msgprint(_("00000"))
    #msgprint(_(found))
    #frappe.errprint(found)
    for selected in self.adding:
        i=i+1
        if selected.selected in found:
            #frappe.throw(_("Duplicate {0}").format(i))
            self.adding[found[selected.selected]].quantity = self.adding[found[selected.selected]].quantity + self.adding[i].quantity
            self.adding[i].quantity = 0
            self.adding[i].selected = 'product-04'
            return edit_quantity_on_hand(selected.selected)

        if selected.selected not in found:
            found[selected.selected] = i
            return edit_quantity_on_hand(selected.selected)


    q='product-04'
    frappe.db.sql("DELETE FROM `tabAdd to Order` WHERE selected = (%s);" ,(q))



  def edit_quantity_on_hand(data):
    quantity_on_hand_f = frappe.db.get_value("Product Details", data, "quantity_on_hand")
    product_name_f = frappe.db.get_value("Product Details", data, "product_name")
    if quantity_on_hand_f - self.adding[found[data]].quantity < 0:
        frappe.throw(_("Quantity on Hand {0} is less than orderd amount ").format(quantity_on_hand_f))

    else :
        quantity_on_hand_f = quantity_on_hand_f - self.adding[found[data]].quantity
        frappe.db.sql("Update `tabProduct Details` Set quantity_on_hand = (%s) Where product_name =(%s); ",(quantity_on_hand_f, product_name_f))
```

How do I call "edit_quantity_on_hand()" in "validate()" function with args ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't specified `edit_quantity_on_hand` as a static method, you need to reference it as an instance method with `self.edit_quantity_on_hand`. Also, that function needs a parameter that includes the instance itself - which it does, but it's `data` at the moment. Use `def edit_quantity_on_hand(self, data):` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```py
def execute(func_name, *args, **kwargs):
    return func_name(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is the extremely simple case, but you can elaborate